# MCP23S17 not working

Tags: spi

Sorry for my broken English in advance.

I am trying to make my atsam4ls2b communicate with an mcp23s17. However, I can not get it to work. I am sending what i think is the correct data over the Mosi pin to the mcp23s17, and when checking the pins with a multimeter I can see that it arrives at the mcp23s17. however it seems like it does nothing with the data. I am hoping anyone can help me out with this problem. Below is my code which is in a loop. it should set all gpio pins to output 3.3v, but it outputs nothing.

```
SPICon->StartTransaction();
SPICon->Transceive(0x40);//select standard first 4 bits(0100) with opcode 000(A2-A1-A0)(opcode is not used for now) and R/W bit on Write (0) (0100-000-0)
SPICon->Transceive(0x0A);//select IO control register
SPICon->Transceive(0x38);//disable slew rate, sequential and enables address pins
SPICon->EndTransaction();

SPICon->StartTransaction();
SPICon->Transceive(0x40);//select standard first 4 bits(0100) with opcode 000(A2-A1-A0)(opcode is not used for now) and R/W bit on Write (0) (0100-000-0)
SPICon->Transceive(0x0B);//select IO control register
SPICon->Transceive(0x38);//disable slew rate, sequential and enables address pins
SPICon->EndTransaction();

SPICon->StartTransaction();
SPICon->Transceive(0x40);//select standard first 4 bits(0100) with opcode 000(A2-A1-A0)(opcode is not used for now) and R/W bit on Write (0) (0100-000-0)
SPICon->Transceive(0x00);//select IO direction register A
SPICon->Transceive(0x00);//set all pins to output
SPICon->EndTransaction();

SPICon->StartTransaction();
SPICon->Transceive(0x40);//select standard first 4 bits(0100) with opcode 000(A2-A1-A0)(opcode is not used for now) and R/W bit on Write (0) (0100-000-0)
SPICon->Transceive(0x01);//select IO direction register B
SPICon->Transceive(0x00);//set all pins to output
SPICon->EndTransaction();

SPICon->StartTransaction();
SPICon->Transceive(0x40);//select standard first 4 bits(0100) with opcode 000(A2-A1-A0)(opcode is not used for now) and R/W bit on Write (0) (0100-000-0)
SPICon->Transceive(0x14);//select Latch A
SPICon->Transceive(0xFF);//set pins to high
SPICon->EndTransaction();

SPICon->StartTransaction();
SPICon->Transceive(0x40);//select standard first 4 bits(0100) with opcode 000(A2-A1-A0)(opcode is not used for now) and R/W bit on Write (0) (0100-000-0)
SPICon->Transceive(0x15);//select Latch B
SPICon->Transceive(0xFF);//set pins to high
SPICon->EndTransaction();
```

where the transceive function is:

```
uint8_t SoftwareSPI::Transceive(uint8_t DataOut)
{
    uint8_t DataIn = 0;

    for(int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
    {
        MoSiPin->SetValue((DataOut >> (7 - i) & 0x01) ? GpioValue::High : GpioValue::Low);
        ClockPin->SetValue(GpioValue::High);

        DelayUs(20);

        GpioValue MisoValue = MiSoPin->GetValue();

        DataIn |= (((uint8_t)MisoValue) << (7 - i));
        ClockPin->SetValue(GpioValue::Low);

        DelayUs(20);
    }

    return DataIn;
}
```

which basicly does: set the mosi pin to the the value of bit i in the byte DataOut -> set the clock pin to high -> delay to make sure changes go through -> put the value of the miso in in bit i of the byte DataIn -> set the clock pin to low -> delay again to make sure changes go through

this happens 8x so it goes through the whole byte.

the StartTransaction and EndTransaction just pull the CS down and up.

the address pins are all 3 connected to the ground, the mosi pin is connected to pinA22, miso to pinA21, clock to pinA20, chipselect to pinB04, vdd and vss are connected to 3.3V and ground. all gpios are just connected to a led for now.

I am using Atmel Studio 7 as compiler.
the program uses some custom made libraries which have been tested correct.

Can anyone see what is wrong here?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Could you describe "can not get it to work" and also the environment a bit? Currently we have a bit of code that uses some unknown libraries, unknown compiler, unknown hardware setup, we don't know what is it supposed to do (or, what the problem is), and neither what have you tried to solve the problem.

Comment: I added some extra info explaining it a bit more

Comment: It's a bit tricky because you have two unknowns - your bitbanged SPI implementation and communication with mcp23s17. Connect MISO to MOSI (without gpio extender), and see if SPI works fine when loopbacked. Have you got an oscilloscope to check what exactly happens on the wire? Have you got a simpler SPI device to try (temperature sensor for example)? Have you checked your clock polarity is correct?

Comment: unfortunately i do not have an oscilloscope to check the wires, nor do i have another spi device. when the MISO and MOSI are connected together it works just like you'd expect. im pretty sure the clock polarity is correct, i switched it around anyway to try but that didn't help.

Comment: Check the errata, I remember something funky with the address pins. These parts do work, I use a lot of them in a commercial product.

Comment: nReset pin? Have you got another SPI master to try maybe? Is bit order correct (LSb/MSb first)?

Comment: the errata says that when IOCON.HAEN = 0 and A2 is high, the device must be adressed as 1xx. but since all Address pins are low i don't think it has to do with this.

Comment: the nReset pin is not connected. and the bit order is correct i think, MSb first, which the datasheet says it should be. I have no other master available

Comment: i tried to connect the nReset pin to 3.3V and it worked :/ sorry for my stupidness and thank you for your help :D

Comment: I would definitely recommend getting either a scope or a logic analyzer for this kind of work. There are very cheap devices available these days that are perfectly adequate for this kind of troubleshooting and can save significant amounts of effort. Look on eBay, aliexpress or similar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

apparently I had to connect the nReset pin to 3.3V aswell, which was not connected before. after connecting the pin everything works perfectly, thanks for the quick responses :D